# Update position of mesh after rotation of THREE.Group()

Tags: three.js

I use a pivot group to rotate my planegeometries instead of each one individually. After rotation of the pivot group-object, I want to find the new positions for each child/planegeometry-mesh to correspond to the positions that is relative to the actual world position.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The easy way**

Like Craig mentioned, [`getWorldPosition`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.getWorldPosition) is a function on `Object3D` (the base class of pretty much everything in the scene), which returns a new `Vector3` of the object's world position.

```
var childPlaneWorldPosition = childPlane.getWorldPosition();
```

**The harder way:**

There are two methods for converting between local and world positions: [`localToWorld`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.localToWorld) and [`worldToLocal`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.worldToLocal).

These are also functions on `Object3D`, and take a `Vector3`. The vector is then (destructively) converted to the desired coordinate system. Just know that it's not smart enough to know if the vector you're giving it is already in the right coordinate system--you'll need to keep track of that.

So, to convert a child plane's position from local to world coordinates, you would do this:

```
// clone because localToWorld changes the vector passed to it
var childPlanePosition = childPlane.position.clone();
childPlane.parent.localToWorld(childPlanePosition);
```

Notice that `localToWorld` is called on `childPlane`'s parent. This is because the `childPlane` is local to its parent, and therefore its position is local to its parent's coordinate system.

**The hard(er to understand) way:**

Each `childPlane` stores not only its local transformation matrix (`childPlane.matrix`), but also its world transformation matrix (`childPlane.matrixWorld`). You can, of course, get the world position directly from the `matrixWorld` property in one step.

```
var childWorldPosition = new THREE.Vector3(
  childPlane.matrixWorld.elements[12],
  childPlane.matrixWorld.elements[13],
  childPlane.matrixWorld.elements[14]
);
```

**Edit to answer some questions**

"*If I understand correctly, can I find the "real" position of the meshes in the pivot-group children-array?*"

Yes. If you called:

```
pivotGroup.add(childPlane);
```

Then that `childPlane` will be listed in the `pivotGroup.children` array, which you could use to iterate over all of the `childPlane` objects

"*And clone these to the position object for each meshes?*"

If you want the planes to be in world coordinates (in the scene), but you used the above code to add them to the group, then they are no longer direct children of the scene. You would need to re-add them to the scene:

```
scene.add(childPlane);
```

And then apply their calculated world positions. That said, why not just leave them in the group?

(You didn't ask this one) "*How would you leave the planes as direct children of the scene, but rotate them as a group?*"

Well, you wouldn't. But three.js does this group rotation by multiplying matrices to come up with finalized world matrices for each plane. So you could do the same thing manually, by creating a rotation matrix, and applying it to all of your planes.

```
var rotMat = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationMatrix(x, y, z);
for(var i = 0; i < planesArray.length; ++i){ // I guess this would loop over your 3D array
  planesArray.applyMatrix(rotMat);
}
```

Comment: So in my case, I have all the meshes in a 3D-array. I use this to check for collision between the player and each mesh. That way I only use the pivot-group to rotate all of them. If I understand correctly, can I find the "real" position of the meshes in the pivot-group children-array? And clone these to the position object for each meshes?

Comment: I've edited my post to answer some of your questions.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this once I get home after the weekend.

Comment: You helped make my code independent from using the pivot group, which actually made me confused. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `plane_mesh.getWorldPosition()`